How to create `AsChild` or `Slot` within Blazor
I have been searching for an answer to this question for a long time. All I want is to be able to recreate the Radix's slot component/asChild pattern within Blazor.
e.g.
<Button AsChild>
    <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
</Button>


Thanks to @DanielD for putting me on the right track.
I created an abstract class (you don't need to do this, you can just add these properties to whichever component you would like to have this functionality).
public abstract class Slot : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter]
    public required RenderFragment<Dictionary<string, object>> ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public bool AsChild { get; set; }
}

Button.razor.cs
Specify the attributes that you would like to get splatted.
public partial class Button : Slot
{
    private static Dictionary<string, object> _attributes =>
        new() { { "onclick", () => Console.WriteLine("Button was clicked!") } };
}

Button.razor
Create the markup for your default component (when AsChild is not being used).
@inherits Slot

@if (AsChild)
{
    @ChildContent(_attributes)
}
else
{
    <button type="button" @attributes="_attributes">
        @ChildContent(_attributes)
    </button>
}

Now you can use the following wherever you like.
Usage of AsChild:
<Button AsChild>
    <a href="#" @attributes="context">Click me!</a>
</Button>

Usage without AsChild:
<Button>
    Click me!
</Button>

